# What is the difference between babel-cli and @babel/cli?

Tags: node.js, babel-cli

What is the difference between `@babel/node` and `babel-node`?
I did `yarn add babel-node --dev` but I had error. 
So I did `yarn add @babel/node --dev`, it worked.
What is the meaning of `@`?

Comment: @barbsan Thank you for your edit!! but I don't know well this site so I rollbacked your edit sorry :(

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, your 2nd rollback rollbacked your 1st rollback, so it contains all changes I've introduced

Comment: @barbsan Thanks!! This site is very interesting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@` signifies the usage of an "npm scope":

https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

It's basically a way to avoid name clashing, so we could both own modules `@cdbrouk/foo` and `@jedrichards/foo`. Babel moved to using the `@babel` scope a while ago, so the `@babel/...` modules are the correct ones to use.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I recently started study
Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: I have changed from "babel-cli" to "@babel/cli" now getting error 
"babel-node": "babel-node --presets=flow" --- 
'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Try installing `@babel/node` too

Comment: I need help, so now how can I run my script from package.json? it's not working if use babel-cli, but when I use @babel/cli is not taking the  --ignore argument.

Answer (score 0):

if you want that your system recongnize the command `babel-node` you should install the dependency `@babel/cli` with the global scope:

```bash
npm install -g @babel/cli
```

Otherwise, you should invoque `babel-node` via npx: `npx babel-node`...